# Error using Nsolve with system of two equations: "Use Reduce"

Tags: equation-solving

Having some odd behavior with some mathematica code I am running. I am solving a simple system of two equations but mathematica gives an error and asks to use Reduce? I looked up in the manual but have no clue what to do to rememdy the situation.

```
delay = 4*10^-9;
gamma = (25*10^3)/0.511;
beta = Sqrt[1 - gamma^-2];
c = 3*10^8;

rho = lb/theta;
drift = 4 lb;

time = (4 rho*theta + 2 drift - 4 lb - 2 drift*Cos[theta])/(beta*c);
disp = lb^2/rho + lb/rho*drift*Cos[theta];

NSolve[{time== delay, disp == 0.6},{theta,lb}]
```

Comment: The expressions for `timeDiff` and `dispersion` are lacking

Comment: oops youre right...fixed!!

Comment: `NSolve` does not handle situations of infinitely many solutions. Could restrict a variable to get to a finite case, e.g. `NSolve[{time == delay, disp == 0.6, -30 <= theta <= 30}, {theta, lb}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:
Thanks to hint by  Daniel below, one can give `NSolve` region to search on.

```
NSolve[{time == delay, disp == 0.6 && (-4 Pi < theta < 4 Pi) && (0 < lb < 10)},
    {theta, lb}]
```

gives

```
{{theta -> -10.6056, lb -> 0.108685}, {theta -> -8.28907, lb -> 0.105523}, 
  {theta -> -3.97865, lb -> 0.089839}, {theta -> -2.80309, lb -> 0.0771901}, 
  {theta -> 1.26384, lb -> 0.214949}, {theta -> 4.68236, lb -> 0.145628}, 
  {theta -> 7.96477, lb -> 0.135066}, {theta -> 10.8505, lb -> 0.131059}}
```

**Original answer**

I do not know why `NSolve` can't solve this since Maple `fsolve` can. But you can use `FindRoot` when all else fails. (the problem with `FindRoot` is that one need to have some idea where to look for)

```
Clear[lb, theta];
delay = 4*10^-9;
gamma = (25*10^3)/0.511;
beta = Sqrt[1 - gamma^-2];
c = 3*10^8;
rho = lb/theta;
drift = 4 lb;
time = (4 rho*theta + 2 drift - 4 lb - 2 drift*Cos[theta])/(beta*c);
disp = lb^2/rho + lb/rho*drift*Cos[theta];
eqs = {time == delay, disp == 0.6};
NSolve[eqs, {theta, lb}, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
roots = FindRoot[eqs, {{theta, -8}, {lb, .1}}]
eqs /. roots
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maple solution:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using Mathematica 10.01 on windows.

Comment: `NSolve` can handle it but requires a restricted domain.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thanks! I actually did not notice that `NSolve` accepts ranges, now it works much better. Updated answer.

Comment: Hey Guys I thought I would try to make things a little easier and give "lb=3;" a try but I get the same error even with lb defined?

Answer (score 1):

```
delay = 4*10^-9;
gamma = (25*10^3)/0.511;
beta = Sqrt[1 - gamma^-2];
c = 3*10^8;
rho = lb/theta;
drift = 4 lb;

time = (4 rho*theta + 2 drift - 4 lb - 2 drift*Cos[theta])/(beta*c);

disp = lb^2/rho + lb/rho*drift*Cos[theta];

ContourPlot[{time == delay, disp == .6},
 {theta, -12, 5}, {lb, 0, .3},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {theta, lb})]
```

[image]

The intersection points are the solution points and provide the initial estimates for `FindRoot`

```
sol = FindRoot[{time == delay, disp == .6},
    {{theta, #[[1]]}, {lb, #[[2]]}}] & /@
  {{-11, .1}, {-8, .1}, {-4, .1}, {-3, .1},
   {2, .2}, {5, .15}}
```

> {{theta -> -10.6056, lb -> 0.108685}, {theta -> -8.28907,    lb ->
>   0.105523}, {theta -> -3.97865,    lb -> 0.089839}, {theta -> -2.80309,    lb -> 0.0771901}, {theta -> 1.26384,    lb -> 0.214949}, {theta ->
>   4.68236, lb -> 0.145628}}

```
{time == delay, disp == .6} /. sol
```

> {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True,
>   True}, {True, True}}

Comment: I tried using Ersek RootSearch, which is supposed to be able to find roots in given range, but on V 10.01 something changed. Now I get `No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.`  This package looks like it is no longer maintained.  http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4482/  It worked ok on version 9.01

Comment: @Nasser I think one can build one by finding the intersections on the interpolation of `grids = Cases[
    Normal@Graphics@
      Cases[ContourPlot[ ...], GraphicsComplex[__], Infinity], 
    Line[__], Infinity] /. Line[a__] -> a;`